# Seeking marriage certificate of Russian and Serbian from about 1900s?

Tags: marriage-records, russia, 1900s-decade, 1890s, serbia

My Serbian Grandfather Milan Marich (born 1880) married Russian Zinaida Dimitrieva Homichevskaya around 1900.

How could I find their marriage certificate?

[image]

[image]

[image]

The last picture is a document of my aunt, daughter of Milan and Zinaida

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE!  We're a little different from other sites; this isn't a discussion forum but a Q&A site.  Please check out our short [tour] to learn about our focussed Q&A format.  Do you know where they married?